# C api migration to Swift 3 in XCode 8 beta 6

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to convert C apis in Swift 3 in XCode 8 beta 6.

```
int payloadSize = 100
char tempBuffer[payloadSize];
memset(tempBuffer, 7, payloadSize);

// Construct the payload.
NSData *payload = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:tempBuffer length:payloadSize];
```

Till XCode 8 beta 3, it was working fine with Swift as:

```
let payloadSize = 100
var tempBuffer:[CChar]?
memset(&tempBuffer, 7, Int(payloadSize))

// Construct the ping packet.
let payload:NSData = NSData(bytes: tempBuffer!, length: Int(payloadSize))
```

But in latest XCode beta release, it is creating crash.

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: If that worked before then by pure chance (or bad luck :) – `tempBuffer` is an optional which you never assigned a value to.

Comment: it just crash, nothing says. it is crashing while creating `NSData` object. Working on XCode 8 beta 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on the line `var tempBuffer:[CChar]?`. That's a declaration of a variable called `tempBuffer`, whose type is `Optional<Array<CChar>>`. It does not define that array, however. When you try to `memset` it, it doesn't work because there is no memory allocated.

Instead of using `memset`, try this instead:

```
let payloadSize = 100
let buffer = [UInt8](repeatedValue: 7 count: payloadSize)

let payload = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: buffer.count)
```

Comment: Then how does it work in swift 2.2 and older xcode beta versions with swift 3. Checkout my actual library https://github.com/ankitthakur/SwiftPing. I am only upgrading it to XCode 8 Beta 6.

Comment: It's likely an in-deterministic issue that only just happened to manifest itself now.

Comment: okay, thanks it worked. C level api integration/migrations is really a pain.

Comment: @AnkitThakur Yeah, try to avoid dealing with C APIs. There's almost always a "Swiftier", way. Most certainly, don't use `memset`. Waant me to show you the bug I found in your original code?

Comment: @Alexandar, could you please review that, and share your inputs in github. thanks for your support.

Comment: No point putting it on github, as it's resolved with this code change. When you were passing `tempBuffer` into memset, you were actually passing in a variable of type `Optional<Array<CChar>>`. Even if there was memory allocated, `memset` would be operating over the `Optional`, and not just the `Array` within it. As you can see in [this demo](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57b5b8a725b042255806a1bf), `Optional` adds on 1 byte to the memory layout to store its enumeration, either `.Some` or `.None`. There's nothing stopping `memset` from overwriting this, and it could easily go **boom**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121258/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-ankit-thakur).